# What does "pace" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

In the Economist this week:

> People have, *pace* vegetarians, evolved to love meat, which contains many necessary nutrients, and especially protein, in higher concentrations than plants do

I'm used to pace meaning "the speed at which one is moving."  Is there another meaning to this word that makes sense in this context, other than perhaps "Slow down, vegetarians! Don't be too hasty to rip into us"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Latin for *peace*. In this context, the writer is indicating that s/he does not want to start an argument with vegetarians.

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense.  It also means my internal vocalization should be "pa-chay" not "pee-se" right?

Comment: Yes, @AffableGeek, that is the normal pronunciation. And I have seen the word used sincerely ("I am not trying to start a debate on  the merits of vegetarianism", or ironically "We all know the vegetarians are going to howl about this, however...").

Comment: But how did vegetarians evolve?

Comment: This is correct. You'll also see similar usage with other communities: for example, google "pace atheists".

Comment: Though not required _per se_, it might be noted, _en passant_ that italics (as seen in the original quote) are often used as an indication of a Latin (or other foreign) word or phrase. At one time it was _de rigueur_ for, _inter alia_ phrases like _vice versa_, _caveat emptor_ _et al_ to be marked this way.

Answer (score 1):

preposition
1.
with all due respect to; with the permission of:
I do not, pace my rival, hold with the ideas of the reactionists.
source: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pace